# How to stylize custom Qt widgets globally?

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qstyle, qpalette

I have custom widgets which inherit `QWidget`.

I'm trying to use the palette, style, and font of the widgets as much as possible, and implement `QWidget::changeEvent()`, to keep their look consistent with the current style.

However, sometimes a widget needs more styling than just what `QStyle` and `QPalette` provide.

Examples for me are:

- The colors of some success, warning, and error sections.
- The font to use for monospace text.

I'd like those to be global, not specified for each widget instance.

I can't find a natural Qt approach to this problem.

My current solution is for those custom widgets to know the specific style class of the application (casting the application style to `QMyStyle&`, for example), but this coupling removes their portability.

How does one make a reusable `QWidget` which needs custom color roles and fonts?

**NOTE**: I don't want to use style sheets because it has its [share of problems](https://www.kdab.com/say-no-to-qt-style-sheets/), some of which I encountered.

Comment: Standard widgets that use aspects not directly provided by the style *do* set them for each instance. For example, the red color used for weekends in QCalendarWidget, which is hardcoded in its constructor. Besides, how would you make those colors or fonts global? Are you trying to find some way of "set one, set all"? That would mean that you'd need to keep track of all instances of that class, or that each instance "subscribes" to some sort of color/font "provider", which could be a QObject that has getter functions queried by each instance and setter ones that would eventually emit a signal.

Comment: Does a QPalette change propagation trigger a change event? I didn't test but would expect that. You can change the application style once everything is shown, right?

Comment: Yes, font and palette changes are always propagated and received by `changeEvent()` (or simply as `PaletteChange` and `FontChange` in `event()`) both when set on the application or any parent in the object tree. You can change the application style at runtime, and it will trigger a `StyleChange` event to all widgets.

Comment: But changing that style means changing the whole object, not just a part of it right?

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the whole object"?

Comment: What I mean is there's no method to call if your custom `QStyle` suddently decides that it will draw some primitives differently, or change the layout spacing, for example. Unlike, for instance, when you know that the size hint of your custom widget will change, you may call `QWidget::updateGeometry()`. But for a `QStyle`, the propagation only happens when setting the style of the application or of a given widget. That's what I understand at the moment at least.

Comment: "*I don't want to use style sheets because it has its share of problems*" -> Is this a "I won't use them" kind of statement? Because if it is, you need to describe the problems you've had so we can see if it is caused by the style sheets or by you. Just to set your expectations right: hoping that, by choosing an alternative to style sheets, you will encounter no downsides is most likely wishful thinking and a [perfect solution fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_fallacy#Perfect_solution_fallacy).